# testInstalledPackage in custom libs folder

Tags: r

Question : How do I make `tools::testInstalledPackage` work when I have a custom lib path defined in Rprofile.site.

I'm not an experience unix user so I might be wrong about this. Theres a line in tools::testInstalledPackage (shown below) which I suppose runs R in vanilla mode, i.e. my custom lib path in Rprofile.site does not get added in.

```
cmd <- paste(shQuote(file.path(R.home("bin"), "R")), 
            "CMD BATCH --vanilla --no-timing", Ropts, shQuote(Rfile), 
            shQuote(failfile))
```

In this case, when I try to test the package `zoo`, `tools::testInstalledPackage` returns a zoo-Ex.Rout.fail file with an error saying that there is no package called 'zoo' which makes sense as vanilla R does not contain my custom Lib folder.

Is there a way to use `tools::testInstalledPackage` to test my packages in my custom folder? Or do I have to copy the folder into the default file path

p.s. my current workaround is to create a new function without the `--vanilla` and attach it to the tools namespace but I don't think its a very elegant solution.